# Cross-section plotting with terrain as background

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Atmospheric Research, the cross-section plots are often used to represent the average meteorology vertical profiles.

Using Python, I can plot the cross-section figure based on netcdf file(Simulation result).
I use this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153816/matplotlib-axis-labels-how-to-find-out-where-they-will-be-located) for reference

But how to represent the terrain in specific cutting line. Example like this:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: What do you mean by "represent the terrain"?

Comment: The black area represent the altitude of the specific place.

Comment: So you want everything below your blue line to be black? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think he wants everything black to be black. The plot is a demonstration. He wants to replicate it in matplotlib. @HanZhengzu You can use fill_between to do this. Here are examples: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html , If you leave some test data I'll work out an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: By reading  `HGT = nc.variables['HGT']` and ploting  with `plt.fill_between(LAT,0,HGT,color="black")`. I can achieve my target.

Answer (score 2):

I've used

```
plt.fill_between(axis, terrain, 0, facecolor='black')
```