# How can I create cross section plots for atmospheric datasets in R?

Tags: r

Is there any packges or way to plot cross-section plots from atmospheric datasets like in this link [Cross-section plotting with terrain as background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502443/cross-section-plotting-with-terrain-as-background) using R.I want to plot cross section of specific humidity,vorticity like parameter at different pressure level.

I searched for the way to do such analysis in R but no luck till now.